# Magento 2: How to manage Floodlight Tags for Pages?

Tags: magento2, cms, websites, tags

Would like to set different **Floodlight Tags** for (Homepage, Different Category Page, Product Page).

How to achieve this?

https://support.google.com/ds/answer/6029713?hl=en

How it will be useful?